Creating a Mac app that acts as a GUI for wget for my specific usecase
I've been trying to create a Mac app that exactly replicates this command:
wget -c --no-check-certificate --tries=inf --waitretry=0 --retry-on-http-error=502,503,504 --read-timeout=5 --connect-timeout=5 -O "{File Directory}/{File Name}.mp4" "{Video Link}"

which downloads a lecture from school so that I can add subtitles and stuff for my own sake.
On Xcode, I've added a few elements to my View Controller so that I can input the name of the file, the video link, and the destination folder for my download. I also added a place where it shows logs of the download progress and stuff. Additionally, I added a function to send me a notification once the download completes.
I'm not a developer. I used ChatGPT (sorry I'm a noob).
Here's the script for ViewController.swift that I believe is the closest thing to what I want to achieve:
import Cocoa
import UserNotifications

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var videoLinkTextField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var fileNameTextField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var destinationFolderTextField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressIndicator: NSProgressIndicator!
    @IBOutlet var logScrollView: NSScrollView!
    
    var logTextView: NSTextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        progressIndicator.isHidden = true
        
        logTextView = NSTextView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: logScrollView.contentSize.width, height: logScrollView.contentSize.height))
        logTextView.isEditable = false
        logTextView.isSelectable = true
        
        logScrollView.documentView = logTextView
        logScrollView.isHidden = true
    }

    @IBAction func chooseDestinationFolder(_ sender: Any) {
        let dialog = NSOpenPanel()
        dialog.title = "Choose a Destination Folder"
        dialog.canChooseDirectories = true
        dialog.canChooseFiles = false
        dialog.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        
        if dialog.runModal() == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK {
            if let url = dialog.url {
                destinationFolderTextField.stringValue = url.path
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func startDownload(_ sender: Any) {
        let videoLink = videoLinkTextField.stringValue
        var fileName = fileNameTextField.stringValue
        let destinationFolder = destinationFolderTextField.stringValue
        
        guard !videoLink.isEmpty, !fileName.isEmpty, !destinationFolder.isEmpty else {
            print("Please provide all required inputs.")
            return
        }
        
        // Ensure file name ends with ".mp4"
        if !fileName.hasSuffix(".mp4") {
            fileName += ".mp4"
        }
        
        let outputPath = (destinationFolder as NSString).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        
        progressIndicator.doubleValue = 0
        progressIndicator.isHidden = false
        
        logScrollView.isHidden = false
        logTextView.string = ""
        
        downloadFile(url: videoLink, outputPath: outputPath)
    }

    func downloadFile(url: String, outputPath: String) {
        let process = Process()
        process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/which")
        
        let arguments = ["wget"]
        process.arguments = arguments
        
        let pipe = Pipe()
        process.standardOutput = pipe
        
        pipe.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = { handle in
            let data = handle.availableData
            if let whichPath = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) {
                let wgetProcess = Process()
                wgetProcess.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: whichPath)
                
                // Setting PATH environment variable
                var environment = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
                environment["PATH"] = "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin"
                wgetProcess.environment = environment
                
                let wgetArguments = [
                    "-c",
                    "--no-check-certificate",
                    "--tries=inf",
                    "--waitretry=0",
                    "--retry-on-http-error=502,503,504",
                    "--read-timeout=5",
                    "--connect-timeout=5",
                    "-O", outputPath,
                    url
                ]
                
                wgetProcess.arguments = wgetArguments
                
                let wgetPipe = Pipe()
                wgetProcess.standardOutput = wgetPipe
                wgetProcess.standardError = wgetPipe
                
                wgetPipe.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = { handle in
                    let data = handle.availableData
                    if let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.logTextView.string += output
                            self.logTextView.scrollToEndOfDocument(nil)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                do {
                    try wgetProcess.run()
                    wgetProcess.waitUntilExit()
                    let status = wgetProcess.terminationStatus
                    if status == 0 {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.progressIndicator.doubleValue = 100
                            self.sendCompletionNotification()
                        }
                    } else {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.logTextView.string += "\nDownload failed with status code \(status)."
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.logTextView.string += "\nError running wget: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                    }
                }
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.logTextView.string += "\nError: wget not found."
                }
            }
        }
        
        do {
            try process.run()
        } catch {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.logTextView.string += "\nError running which command: \(error.localizedDescription)"
            }
        }
    }

    func sendCompletionNotification() {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Download Completed"
        content.body = "Your video file has been downloaded successfully."
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
        
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "downloadComplete", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error adding notification request: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}


The problem is that when I run this, there's always a error that my permission is denied when I try to access wget.
Error running wget. The operation couldn't be completed. Permission denied.
ChatGPT suggested multiple solutions but none of them worked.
The wget command works fine on terminal, but I just want to simplify the process for the future. Any other commands like curl, ffmpeg, aria2c, and yt-dlp did not work for my usecase.
Can you help me with getting permission for wget?
I've checked the filepath for wget multiple times, checked whether it's the most updated version, change the filepath (which resulted in "cannot find wget"), etc etc.
